# Get name, locale etc in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.6

This may be very easy but I just can't find it.

When we use `getLocale()` we get value from `config.app` file, right?

In that file I have `'locale'=>'en'`

Also there are other things like `'name'`, when I try to use `app()->getName() or app()->name()` it says it doesn't exist.

It works with `config('app.name') same as config('app.locale')`, I would like to know how does it work with locale but doesn't work for name?

Also I was searching for these methods `getLocale` but I can't find them that's main reason why am I asking this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function is declared at line 1039 in the Application class (**Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:1039**) of **Laravel 5.6**.

That's why it's working for `app()->getLocale()` and not `app()->getName()`.

```
/**
 * Get the current application locale.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getLocale()
{
    return $this['config']->get('app.locale');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I added for name and others I need :D